# JSLint : Why this warning?

Tags: jslint

Why JSLint is producing this kind of warning

*Problem at line xxx character yyy: Expected 'X' to have an indentation at xx instead at yyy.*

Why does it matter to have a different space formatting?

Comment: Please show a code fragment that triggers this warning.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you didn't show us the line, we can only guess, but it's probably something like this.

```
 if(someCondition)
     DoThis();
     DoThat();
```

Since it would expect the indenting to be:

```
 if(someCondition)
     DoThis();
 DoThat();
```

It thinks you may want it to be:

```
 if(someCondition)
 {
     DoThis();
     DoThat();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have indented something that shouldn't be indented, or shouldn't be indented as much.

This often happens after declaring several variables:

```
var foo,
    bar;
    baz = something;
```

or with if statements as @James Curran mentioned. Just go to line xxx and see if something is indented that shouldn't be. If you can't find it, post the section og the code in the question and let us have a look.

Answer (score 0):

As James points out, it's likely a spacing issue.

```
var spam = 3;

if (3 === spam) {
spam = 4;
}
```

... gives me `Expected 'spam' at column 5, not column 1.`

If whitespace isn't something you want JSLint to check (and it generally isn't for me), you have two choices to turn off "sloppy whitespace" checks.  On the site (or in your tool of choice), you can check "white", or you can add a directive at the top of your file, like this:

```
/*jslint white:true*/
var spam = 3;

if (3 === spam) {
spam = 4;
}
```

Now I get a clean bill o' lint.